Show that the ODE $y' = 1 - (\sin^{2}(x))y^{4} , y(0)=0$ has solution for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$ (global existence)
$$y' = 1 - (\sin^{2}(x))y^{4} , y(0)=0$$ $y'(0) = 1 > 0 $ so $y(x)$ is an increasing function close to $x=0$.
There are $x_{0} > 0$ and $x_{1} < 0$ such that $y(x) > y(0) = 0 $ for $x\in(0,x_{0})$ and $y(x) < y(0) = 0 $ for $x\in (x_{1},0)$. I can see that $y(x) > 0 $ for $x>0$ and $y(x) < 0 $ for $x<0$. Using the comparison theorem I compare $1 - (\sin^{2}(x))y^{4}$ with $1$, so I compare $y(x)$ with $y_{1}(x) = x$ and I have that $$\left| y(x)\right|\leq \left| x\right|.$$ The function $\left| x\right|$ is finite, so does $\left| y(x)\right|$ (there are no explosions).
Is there another way to solve this problem? Is my way of thinking correct? I didn'texplain every detail but I hope everything is clear enough

Since $f(x,y)=1-(\sin^2(x))y^4$ is a local Lipschitz function, so there is small $\delta>0$ such that for $x\in(-\delta,\delta)$, the ODE $y'=f(x,y), y(0)=0$ has a unique solution. Extend $y$ to the maximal interval $(-a,b)$. Now one has to show $a=b=\infty$. Suppose $b<\infty$; namely
$$ \lim_{x\to b^-}|y(x)|=\infty $$
which is against the conclusion $|(y(x)|\le|x|$ you made. Similarly $a=\infty$.
